# Why I can't ping internal network IP addresses

Tags: linux, networking, centos, firewall, ping

I am not a system engineer (I am more a software developer). I am working on some CentOS 7 machines on the same network.

I have the following problem. Basically trying to ping from one machine to another one (in the same network) I obtain nothing:

[image]

As you can see in the previous screenshot, it seems to not respond.

If instead of an internal IP I try to ping an external system (like "google.com") it works fine.

What could be the causes of this problem? What can I try to do to investigate? It could be something related to the firewall? (internal machine firewall or an external firewall)

How can I correctly perform a reachability test? I need to ensure that these machines can communicate with each other.

Comment: If all the computers are in the same network segment (IP `192.168.130.X`), then look for a blocking firewall. Note that weird firewall config might block ping but allow other connections, so also try perhaps `telnet`.

Comment: Could it be the machines are blocking ping (ICMP traffic) ? Check out https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-managing_icmp_requests for options on how to enable this in redhat/centos

Comment: Check your arp tables or use arpping.  You can't block arp and still function on the network.